# Getting Averages of numbers in textboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have textboxes that gives a sum and I want to collect the sums and get an average on them. There are three judges so an average of those three sums. here is the code, it is the same as my last 'judging' code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="text"size="3"></p>
<h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input id="txt1" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"35">     /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt2" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt3"type="text"size="3"min="0" max"25">   /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt4" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15">  /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt5"type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</br>
<h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>

</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input id="txt6" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"35"   onkeyup="sum();"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt7" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15"  onkeyup="sum();"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input id="txt8" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"25"   onkeyup="sum();"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input  id="txt9"type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15"   onkeyup="sum();"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input  id="txt10"type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input  id="txt11"type="text"size="3" min="0" max"35">  /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt12" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15">  /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt13"type="text"size="3"min="0" max"25">  /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt14" type="text"size="3"min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt15" type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Get Score">
<p> Overall Score:</p>
<p> Award Assigned:</p>
</form>
</body>
<script>
function sum() {
   var txt1NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
   var txt2NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
   var txt3NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
   var txt4NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
   var txt6NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt6').value;
   var txt7NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt7').value;
   var txt8NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt8').value;
   var txt9NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt9').value;
   var txt11NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt11').value;
   var txt12NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt12').value;
   var txt13NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt13').value;
   var txt14NumberValue = document.getElementById('txt14').value;
   if (txt1NumberValue == "")
       txt1NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt2NumberValue == "")
       txt2NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt3NumberValue == "")
       txt3NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt4NumberValue == "")
       txt4NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt6NumberValue == "")
       txt6NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt7NumberValue == "")
       txt7NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt8NumberValue == "")
       txt8NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt9NumberValue == "")
       txt9NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt11NumberValue == "")
       txt11NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt12NumberValue == "")
       txt12NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt13NumberValue == "")
       txt13NumberValue = 0;
   if (txt14NumberValue == "")
       txt14NumberValue = 0;

   var result = 0;
   result = parseInt(txt1NumberValue) + parseInt(txt2NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt3NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt4NumberValue);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('txt5').value = result;
   }
   result = parseInt(txt6NumberValue) + parseInt(txt7NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt8NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt9NumberValue);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('txt10').value = result;
   }
   result = parseInt(txt11NumberValue) + parseInt(txt12NumberValue)+    parseInt(txt13NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt14NumberValue);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('txt15').value = result;
   }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: [DRY!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: what error are you getting?what are you trying to get an average?

Comment: @retrogirl19 -  accept the answer if you find it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="text" size="3"></p>

    <h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
    <form class="group group1">
      <p> Technique:  <input id="txt1" type="text" class="score" size="3">     /35</p>
      <p> Choreography:  <input id="txt2" type="text" class="score" size="3"> /15</p>
      <p> Performance: <input  id="txt3" type="text" class="score" size="3">   /25</p>
      <p> Precision:  <input id="txt4" type="text" class="score" size="3">  /15</p>
      <p> Total Points: <input id="txt5" type="text" class="result" size="3">  /90</p>
      <p> Comments</p>
      <textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </br>
    </form>

    <h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>
    <form class="group group1">
      <p> Technique:  <input id="txt6" type="text" class="score" size="3">     /35</p>
      <p> Choreography:  <input id="txt7" type="text" class="score" size="3"> /15</p>
      <p> Performance: <input  id="txt8" type="text" class="score" size="3">   /25</p>
      <p> Precision:  <input id="txt9" type="text" class="score" size="3">  /15</p>
      <p> Total Points: <input id="txt10" type="text" class="result" size="3">  /90</p>
      <p> Comments</p>
      <textarea name="commentsTwo" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </br>
    </form>

    <h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
    <form class="group group1">
      <p> Technique:  <input id="txt11" type="text" class="score" size="3">     /35</p>
      <p> Choreography:  <input id="txt12" type="text" class="score" size="3"> /15</p>
      <p> Performance: <input  id="txt13" type="text" class="score" size="3">   /25</p>
      <p> Precision:  <input id="txt14" type="text" class="score" size="3">  /15</p>
      <p> Total Points: <input id="txt15" type="text" class="result" size="3">  /90</p>
      <p> Comments</p>
      <textarea name="commentsThree" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </br>
    </form>

    <input type="submit" value="Get Score">
    <p> Overall Score:</p>
    <p> Award Assigned:</p>

    <script>

window.onload = function () {
  // Create a collection of elements that have the "group" class.  This will produce a
  // collection with your 3 forms.
  var groups = document.getElementsByClassName('group');

  // Loop through the collection and attach a handler to the "keyup" event of each <form>
  for (var i = 0, len = groups.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    groups.item(i).addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler);
  }
}

// This is the handler that will fire whenever a <form> receives a "keyup" event.  It
// takes a single parameter - the "event object" which holds information about the event
// such as which key was pressed, or which mouse button was clicked.
// You can find out more about the event object here:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event
// The handler also has a "this" parameter, which refers to the <form> that received the
// "keyup" event.  If we call "this.getElementsByClassName('score')", it will return only the
// elements that have the class "score" *AND* are inside the <form> that received the
// event.  This makes calculating each judge's score much easier.
function keyUpHandler (e) {
  // Create a collection, similar to the "groups" collection
  var scores = this.getElementsByClassName('score');
  var sum = 0;
  var score;

  // Loop through all the scores in the collection and add them together
  for (var i = 0, len = scores.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    score = parseInt(scores.item(i).value) || 0;
    sum += score;
  }

  // Update the form with the new sum, in the "result" textbox.
  this.getElementsByClassName('result').item(0).value = sum;
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A few notes:

1. `<input type="text">` does not have `min` or `max` attributes.  Those are for `<input type="number">` which you may want to use instead.
2. Your `max` attributes were mostly missing the `=` operator, and hence would have been ignored even if they had been attached to an `<input type="number">`
3. Try not to give every object you want to work with an `id`.  This is an anti-pattern and results in code like your example, which can be a nightmare to maintain.  Favour `class`es over `id`s
4. You had an extra `</form>` without an opening `<form>` tag.  Keeping your code tidy and indented properly can help avoid problems like this.
5. You had your first "Judge 1" heading outside the corresponding form, then your subsequent headings at the end of the preceeding forms?  This could get really confusing.  Consistency is important.
6. You don't need to attach a handler to every individual `<input>` element (which you were doing by `... onkeyup="sum()"`).  You can attach a single handler to the `<form>` element itself.  This is called [Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and is a very helpful thing to understand.
7. To add an "average" feature, you will need this line a few times in your HTML:

   1. `<p> Average: <input type="text" class="average" size="3"></p>`

   and these lines in the `keyUpHandler` function:

   1. `this.getElementsByClassName('average').item(0).value = average;`
   2. `var average;`
   3. `average = sum / scores.length;`

   I leave it up to you to determine where :)

Comment: Great - I'm glad to help.  Would you care to accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You get an average by summarizing the values and then dividing them by the amount of different values. So in your case with 4 different values, you have to divide the sum by 4.

So to get the Average. Just write the following:

```
average = result/4;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Since there is not much clarity what are you trying,based on your inputs,i assume you want to calculate average result on the marks given by 3 judges.*

```
       var *result* = parseInt(txt1NumberValue) + parseInt(txt2NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt3NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt4NumberValue);

       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt5').value = result;
       }

       var **result1** = parseInt(txt6NumberValue) + parseInt(txt7NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt8NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt9NumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt10').value = result1;
       }
       var **result2** = parseInt(txt11NumberValue) + parseInt(txt12NumberValue)+    parseInt(txt13NumberValue)+ parseInt(txt14NumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt15').value = result2;
       }
    var avergage=(result+ result1 +result2)/3
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will make ur life easier and also provide you the average

[JSBin for trial](http://jsbin.com/zanizok/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function getSum(className) {
  var result = 0;
  var classGroup = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for(var i =0; i < classGroup.length; (i = i + 1))
  {    
    result += parseInt((classGroup[i].value || 0), 10);
  }

  return result;

}

function sum() {    

  var result1 = getSum('jd1');
  var result2 = getSum('jd2');
  var result3 = getSum('jd3');

  console.log('sum' + result1 + '' + result2 + '' + result3);

  document.getElementById('txt5').value = result1;
  document.getElementById('txt10').value = result2;
  document.getElementById('txt15').value = result3;


  document.getElementById('avg').innerHTML = (result1 + result2 + result3)/3;  
}
```

Below is the html code!

```
<p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="text"size="3"></p>
<h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input class="jd1" id="txt1" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"35">     /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt2" class="jd1" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt3" class="jd1" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"25">   /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt4" class="jd1" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"15">  /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt5"type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</br>
<h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>

</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input id="txt6" type="text" class="jd2" size="3" min="0" max"35"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt7" type=" class="jd2" text"size="3" min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input id="txt8" type="text" class="jd2" size="3" min="0" max"25"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input  id="txt9" class="jd2" type="text" size="3" min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input  id="txt10"type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
</form>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input  id="txt11" class="jd3" type="text"size="3" min="0" max"35">  /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt12" type="text" class="jd3" size="3" min="0" max"15">  /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt13" class="jd3" type="text" size="3" min="0" max"25">  /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt14" type="text" size="3" class="jd3" min="0" max"15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt15" type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</form>
<input type="button"  onclick="sum()" value="Get Score">
<p> Overall Score:</p>
  <p> Award Assigned:<span id="avg"></span></p>
</form>
```